# Showing that a given relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f : A → B$ be a function. Define a relation $∼$ on $A$ by $a ∼ a'$
if $f(a) = f(a')$ for all $a$ and $a'\in A$. Prove that $∼$ is an equivalence relation.

I'm having trouble with the notation here. I know I have to show that $~$ is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric but I don't really know how.

My guess is this:

assume $f(a) = f(a)$. This implies $a ∼ a$. So this is reflexive.

assume $f(a) = f(a')$. So then $f(a') = f(a)$ so we have that $a ∼ a'$ implies $a' ∼ a$. So this is symmetric

assume $f(a) = f(a')$ and $f(a') = f(a'')$. So then we have that $a ∼ a'$ and $a' ∼ a''$. So since $f(a) = f(a'')$ we have $a ∼ a''$. So this is transitive.

I really don't think this is right but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is exactly right!

Comment: @TimRaczkowski ok cool. I was kind of worried. It seemed too trivial to be an actual question.

Comment: Well it's based on the properties of the equality relation, which are exactly the properties required for an equivalence relation.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: A slight nit-pick: For reflexive you need not "assume" $f(a)=f(a)$ since it is true for any function $f$ and any $a$ in its domain, [Then you still get $a$ equivalent to $a$.]

Comment: Some equivalence classes are easier than others.  Ones involving equality are the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

A skeleton proof that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation would look like:

- Let $a \in A$. ... [you fill in] ... so $a \sim a$.
- Let $a,b \in A$. Assume $a \sim b$, i.e. $f(a)=f(b)$. Then ... [you fill in] ... so $b \sim a$.
- Let $a,b,c \in A$. Assume $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, i.e. $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f(b)=f(c)$. Then ... [you fill in] ... so $a \sim c$.

As per coffee math's comment, you don't really have to assume anything in the reflexivity part of the proof.

Hint: the last step before you write "so $x \sim y$" as a conclusion would be "$f(x)=f(y)$, so $x \sim y$".

<strike>By the way, your definition of $\sim$ should be $a \sim a'$ **iff** $f(a)=f(a')$.</strike> **Edit**: I was wrong on this last point about **iff** - see comment below.

Comment: On the last comment, that is more of a convention. Similar to how in definitions, you do not explicitly say if and only if.